# ArrayList.IndexOf( wild card? )

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm trying to find the index of the first element of an ArrayList whose 'tag' property  does not equal null.

I thought I could do something to the effect of

```
ArrayList.IndexOf(p => p.tag != null);
```

or

```
ArrayList.IndexOf(*.tag != null);
```

but neither of these work. Is there a way to use IndexOf with just a property of an object?

Comment: What is 'tag' property of ArrayList?

Comment: If you can, you should use List<T> instead of ArrayList. ArrayLists are "démodé". But see my solution below.

Comment: is this .NET 2.0? Is LINQ even an option?

Comment: He is using lambdas, so I think it needs to be at least 3.0

Comment: @yetanothercoder 'tag' is a property of the objects in the ArrayList

Comment: @brokenglass @xanatos This project uses .NET 2.0 I didn't know lambdas were not in 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`Array.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy.aspx):

> Searches for an element that matches
>   the conditions defined by the
>   specified predicate, and returns the
>   zero-based index of the first
>   occurrence within the entire Array.

Comment: That is for an Array. The OP was asking for an ArrayList.

Comment: Though I did ask for an ArrayList, converting to an Array and using Array.FindIndex solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to using a generic List instead of ArrayList, you can do this:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(p => p.tag != null);
```

Otherwise, you're stuck having to manually (*gasp*) loop through the array list.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the type of the objects you could do something like this

```
ArrayList list = ...;
var elem = list.Cast<T>().Select((item,i) => new {item,Index = i}).FirstOrDefault(p => p.item.tag == null);
var index = elem != null ? elem.Index : -1;
```

will work if you know there's at least one (not that effecient mind you

Cast turns an `IEnumerable` into a `IEnumerable<T>` opening up the door to the rest of LINQ

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = a.Cast<T>()
             .Select((p, q) => p != null && p.tag != null ? q + 1 : 0)
             .FirstOrDefault(p => p > 0) - 1;
```

Returns `-1` if no element found.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with IndexOf is that you have to use as a parameter an Object in the collection. It is not a LINQ extension. That is why it fails because your lambda is not in the collection.

You could also use the following LINQ query

`ArrayList.IndexOf(ArrayList.First( x => p.tag != null ))`

But regarding the performance it'll be a bit poor (looking through the collection twice)

You should rather refactor your code as suggested by the smart answers around mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do this while still using the ArrayList you can simply call ToArray() then do your FindIndex